# nt use one feature as a "node" for decision tree in the subgroup of another feature

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have a following data:

```
+------------+------------------+-----+-------------------------------+-------+
| Patient Id | requires surgery | age | days_from_hospital_to_surgery | alive |
+------------+------------------+-----+-------------------------------+-------+
|          1 | yes              |  40 | 5                             | yes   |
|          2 | no               |  50 | nul1                          | no    |
+------------+------------------+-----+-------------------------------+-------+
```

The outcome is "alive" and I want to use decision tree to analyze it. The question is, "days_from_hospital_to_surgery" is not existent for patients who did not receive surgery. How can I deal with this variable? Decision tree cannot handle missing values, and I hope when arriving at the node "do surgery", "days_from_hospital_to_surgery" will only appear at the branch "do surgery"=yes. How can I make this? Thank you very much.

Comment: What tool do you use in order to create this decision tree?

Comment: python sklearn DecisionTreeClassifier

Comment: Can you provide a code example?